# WCF 4.5 - multiple web services

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, visual-studio-2012

I would like to consume 2 WCF web services located on 2 different hosts (the first accessible in HTTPS and the second one in HTTP). Both present the same methods, but the first one is on the production server, while the second one is on a test server.

When I add the references in my Visual Studio 2012 (express), I get 2 namespaces ; for now, the only way I found to consume these services is to use the interfaces and classes generated in these namespaces.
I would like to use only one web service, depending of a configuration item, indicating if I'm in debug or release mode.
How can I do that by code ?

Here is my config file :

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ILotWebContract">
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ILotWebContract1" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://xxx/Services/WebService/LotWebService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ILotWebContract"
            contract="eMol.ILotWebContract" name="BasicHttpBinding_ILotWebContract" />
        <endpoint address="http://yyy/Services/WebService/LotWebService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ILotWebContract1"
            contract="eMolTest.ILotWebContract" name="BasicHttpBinding_ILotWebContract1" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I tried to change the endpoint's address :

```
eMolTest.LotWebContractClient client = new eMolTest.LotWebContractClient();
client.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("https://xxx/Services/WebService/LotWebService.svc");
client.Endpoint.Binding = new System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding(System.ServiceModel.SecurityMode.Transport);
```

but the exception generated while running the client indicate that the links between client and service probably do not correspond.

I also tried to indicate the name of the endpoint when I call the proxy's contructor :

```
eMolTest.LotWebContractClient client = new eMolTest.LotWebContractClient("BasicHttpBinding_ILotWebContract");
```

but again it does not work because of the namespaces which are different (the contract's name contains the namespace's name, and can therefore not be found in the endpoint as defined in the config file).

So, if someone has a good idea ...

Thanks !
Chris

Comment: This may be a case where manually creating the proxy may be your best option instead of using the automatic tools built in to Visual Studio.

Comment: You should have 1 service that you deploy to two different locations. Then you only need 1 service reference and you can just update the app.config file to point at the correct one for what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two services with the exact same contract, you should share it's contract as a **contract assembly** between all three parties and use a [ChannelFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576132.aspx) class to create the proxy yourself. That way you don't have two service references that although they represent the same contract are incompatible from a compiler perspective.